# What to use to divide longitude on smaller parts than time zones?

Tags: latitude-longitude

I have a database of earth's grid, I have consolidated elements from 1152x576 to 360°x180° and then those degrees into geographical zones and time zones so I get 5(6) geographical zones (N/S frigid, N/S temperate, (N/S) torrid) and ~24 time zones ((+/-)0, +1 to +12 (or +-12) and -12 to -1) and that's the problem, because it's 5:24 zones (latitude:longitude) and it's bad ratio.

I am displaying those zones in a table and it doesn't look well, when the x axis is 5 times longer than y axis. Is there widely used consolidation of longitude into less, but bigger areas?

I was thinking for example about 8 areas, 4 on western and 4 on eastern hemisphere, but I could't find if this division of longitude exists. Would it be somthing like WWW, WWE, WEW, WEE, EWW, EWE, EEW, EEE? Is it used normally so the people looking into my database will understand it? I can make it look like "WWW (0°-45°)" etc, I think it will be the best, am I right?

EDIT: I encountered a new problem, that this division of longitude has different borders than division on time zones, time zone start on 7.5° + x*15° and this division would start on 0° + x*45°, so I couln't consolidate 3 time zones into one portion of 45° and I consolidated those 2 approaches separately.

Comment: What is the purpose of this "consolidation"?

Comment: To don't have 360 parts (degrees), but something smaller to better display results in a table, because I can't display 360 elements or I don't want to display 24 elements (timezones), but <=12 and more than 4 elements would be optimal, I have already made 8 parts of 45° and beside that 24 timezones in different branch of my tree structure.

Comment: Normally one selects zones appropriate for whatever one is studying rather than for convenience in tabulation: there are all kinds of ways to present tables.  What kinds of data are you tabulating?

Comment: Pressure, heating rates, ozone rates, number of clouds etc and I want to display a grid like 8x6 with averaged values from that area. So I have it now like WWW, WWE, WEW, WEE, EWW, EWE, EEW and EEE on longitude and North frigid zone, north temp. zone, torrid zone (north) and the same on south on latitude.

Comment: The solution depends on whether you're doing vector operations, using point coordinates, or working on raster data.  Which methods are you using?

Comment: So what is solution for each of your methods?

Comment: Salda, we are a question *and then* answer site, not the other way around. Please clarify your question rather than asking for all answers to all possible related questions!